# Is there any interpreter stage for eBPF programs?

Tags: runtime, ebpf, interpretation

I'm new to eBPF, as the tutorial suggests, eBPF is a runtime with a jit compiler. As far as I am concerned, the bytecode is just translated into native code in eBPF, so I wonder if there is any interpretation stage like JVM in eBPF?

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the JIT compiler, then yes, it will be interpreted.

You can disable the JIT compiler with:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/core/bpf_jit_enable
```

or in the kernel config. with:

```
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=n
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Linux kernel, eBPF comes both with an interpreter and (for all wide-spread architectures) a JIT-compiler.

You can use either the interpreter or the JIT-compiler for your programs. This is controlled through the [`bpf_jit_enable`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/net.html?highlight=jit_enable#proc-sys-net-core-network-core-options) knob for `sysctl`. They are not different stages of the execution process: When you use the interpreter, the kernel *interprets* your program and emulates registers; whereas with the JIT-compiler enabled, you get your instructions compiled into native code.

This being said, the interpreter is not *always* available. For security reasons (related to Spectre), some distributions will leave it out when compiling the kernel, by setting the kernel config option `CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON=y`. In that case, the interpreter cannot be used.